# flink kubernetes operator throws ReconciliationException: java.lang.NullPointerException while batch job has already finished

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-batch

flink operator version is v1.5
Deployment recovery has been turned off in the configuration by setting **kubernetes.operator.jm-deployment-recovery.enabled to false.**

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: 
  labels:
    upgradeMode: savepoint
spec:
  image: 
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "3"
    # taskmanager.memory.managed.size: 2m
    jobmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: "256mb"
    # classloader.resolve-order: parent-first
    kubernetes.decorator.hadoop-conf-mount.enabled: "false"
  serviceAccount: flink
  podTemplate:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: pod-template
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regsecret    
      containers:
        # Do not change the main container name
        - name: flink-main-container
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /opt/flink/application.properties
            name: flink-config
            subPath: application.properties
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: flink-config-rcmd
        name: flink-config
  jobManager:
    replicas: 1
    resource:
      cpu: 0.2
      memory: 1024m
  taskManager:
    resource:
      cpu: 0.2
      memory: 2048m
  job:
    args:
    - --path
    - /opt/flink/application.properties
    entryClass: 
    jarURI: 
    parallelism: 3
    state: running
    upgradeMode: stateless
```

the log

2023-11-16 02:54:09,485 o.a.f.k.o.c.FlinkDeploymentController [INFO ][xxx] Starting reconciliation
2023-11-16 02:54:09,485 o.a.f.k.o.s.FlinkResourceContextFactory [INFO ][xxx] Getting service for xxx
2023-11-16 02:54:09,485 o.a.f.k.o.o.JobStatusObserver  [INFO ][xxx] Observing job status
2023-11-16 02:54:09,492 o.a.f.k.o.o.JobStatusObserver  [INFO ][xxx] Job status changed from RUNNING to FINISHED
2023-11-16 02:54:09,505 o.a.f.k.o.l.AuditUtils         [INFO ][xxx] >>> Event  | Info    | JOBSTATUSCHANGED | Job status changed from RUNNING to FINISHED
2023-11-16 02:54:09,510 o.a.f.k.o.o.SavepointObserver  [ERROR][xxx] Could not observe latest savepoint information.
java.lang.NullPointerException
2023-11-16 02:54:09,522 o.a.f.k.o.l.AuditUtils         [INFO ][xxx] >>> Event  | Warning | CLUSTERDEPLOYMENTEXCEPTION | java.lang.NullPointerException
2023-11-16 02:54:09,522 o.a.f.k.o.r.ReconciliationUtils [WARN ][xxx] Attempt count: 5, last attempt: false
2023-11-16 02:54:09,523 i.j.o.p.e.ReconciliationDispatcher [ERROR][tms-test/content-agg] Error during event processing ExecutionScope{ resource id: ResourceID{name='content-agg', namespace='tms-test'}, version: 1943523107} failed.
org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.exception.ReconciliationException: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.exception.ReconciliationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
2023-11-16T10:54:09.523616673+08:00     at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.controller.FlinkDeploymentController.reconcile(FlinkDeploymentController.java:156)
2023-11-16T10:54:09.523618777+08:00     at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.controller.FlinkDeploymentController.reconcile(FlinkDeploymentController.java:57)

This is a scheduled job. If the problem has not solved, the job cannot be executed next time.